# Can you authenticate, then make multiple dependent requests for data using Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, a user can log in, then a list of their "pages" (a collection of documents) is retrieved, and their "selectedPageId" is retrieved. This way the UI can show a list of page names, and the content of the selected page.

This means three requests have to happen, each waiting for the other:

- log in
- get list of pages
- get selected page id

Is there a way to make all this happen on the server at once so I can make a single request, which I assume would make my UI render more quickly?

Comment: Firebase Auth will still be required on client side (logging in user after they enter credentials). You could use a [callable cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and run the pages queries there so it's technically 1 API request from your web app but it's just adding some overhead of functions. You are running the same queries but not directly. I would recommend querying directly using Firestore SDKs as this is pretty straightforward and secure with security rules.

Comment: What exactly "a list of their 'pages'" consists in? How many fields per page? Is there a limit for the number of pages for a user?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec its a list of documents in a collection, I edited to make that more clear. The fields and limit don't seem like they would affect the answer.

Comment: @Dharmaraj my concern is the time taken before the user can see/interact with the page, not the security or complexity. Cloud functions are probably the way to go here, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As Dharmaraj mentioned in his comment, "Firebase Auth will still be required on client side". **However**, is you use the default [Auth state persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#supported_types_of_auth_state_persistence) (i.e. `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL`) once a user is signed in he/she doesn't need to sign in the next times ("the state will be persisted even when the browser window is closed. An explicit sign out is needed to clear that state"). So signing in is not really a problem IMO.

For the Firestore queries: Executing the two queries back-to-back with the second one returning only one document should not take a lot of extra time compare to executing only the first query (which fetches the pages list).

---

Having said that, one possible approach would be to save, for each user, a Firestore **document** containing the list of the user's pages plus the user's `selectedPageId`. You can maintain this page with a Cloud Function which, for example, mirrors the list (documents in a collection) with an array in this Firebase doc. However, you need to take care to not reach the maximum size for a document i.e. 1MiB (hence my question on the number of fields displayed for a page).

One possible variation in this case would be to initially present, in your first app page, a limited number (e.g. 25) of pages of the list, with a "Show more" button.

---

Finally, note that using a Cloud Function as mentioned in the above comments will very most probably increase the response time compare to standard queries executed via the SDK.

Comment: Thank you for this. I found that executing the queries back to back could add up to something like 1 second of wait time. I forgot to mention that I also check the user claims with `user.getIdToken()` and `user.getIdTokenResult()` which takes additional time. Any thoughts on those?

Comment: Hmmm… if you need to check the user’s claims, I don’t think you’ll be able to avoid calling one of these methods… More generally speaking, at the Firebase Summit 2019 there was a very interesting talk about a smart technique consisting in using the REST API for the first fetch of the app: https://youtu.be/DHbVyRLkX4c. I’m not sure it would help you in your case but it worth watching IMO to maybe get some insights.